# I believe my Domain has been hijacked I am not receiving in sales in shopping cart

Tags: dns

My IP address is 181.224.153.95  Domain: www.ashaybythebay.com

FTP Hostname: m23.siteground.biz

I added private domain servers to my domain name ashaybythebay.com and I see the two IP server addresses listed in my DNS settings. Here they are on the robtex.com report.

```
ns1.ashaybythebay.com.  600 IN  A   181.224.153.233 
ns2.ashaybythebay.com.  600 IN  A   181.224.153.234
```

The server IP address are listed in Panama.

Yet on my cpanel I see two other DNS server IP addresses and my server is supposed to be located in Chicago.  Here they are:

```
ns1.m23.siteground.biz (184.154.158.138) 
ns2.m23.siteground.biz (181.224.153.102)
```

My shopping cart states that my server also is 184.154.158.138

Since discovering this I have denied both private DNS IP servers to keep the hackers out.

What do you think is happening?

Comment: Did you start having problems with your shopping cart after you denied the siteground IPs, or before?

Comment: The Problems were happening before. But the theieves keep trying different ways to take over my domaine. They keep hacking my home network. I shut them down and they get back in. And it is hard to run an online business. It is a hate cyber group.

Comment: You might want to shutdown network connections and examine log files to try to find the breach. It is possible that the attackers have installed network backdoors on your systems.

Comment: Did you register your site with siteground? I see that it's your FTP destination. If so, it simply looks like they offer their DNS services for the domain they host for you. I'm not seeing a problem here.

Answer (score 1):

We had something similar two years ago. Someone hijacked our DNS account at our domain hosting provider. They changed the email DNS for one domain, the one linked to our main Amazon account. We had two-factor authorization, but they convinced Amazon to disable this - probably they had the last digits of our credit card but we are not sure how this happened and Amazon didn't tell us about this. Then they had control over our Amazon account, and they could start and stop instances.

We had two parties involved: the DNS host and Amazon. The DNS host denied that they were hacked, but they helped us actively in blocking all DNS changes to our domains. For some reason Amazon could not throw out the logged in users, so it was a constant battle between us and them to undo their actions. After one day they were automatically logged out and could not login anymore.

For you it's about getting control back over DNS, and with that your DNS hosting provider should help you actively, and they should block any changes to your account for a while without phone contact or something.

Answer (score 0):

I work in a company, where we design webshops, i just talked to my boss/tutor about this, and he explained that hijacking (and if you are unlucky, even take control over it!) is getting more popular, mostly to change some names here and there (i.e., payment methods), so buyers will pay the intruders, instead of the owner (you), mostly with bitcoin addresses, paypal, obtaining credit card details etc.

this is mostly prevented by having your online webshop in a framework, think of something like Magento (http://www.magento.com), and hosting your domain/webshop on a secure location.

in the Netherlands, we have something called SIDN.  It's one central place, that says if the registar/host is trusted, it's even illigal to be a host/registar, without SIDN's permission, making sure that the host/register/dns has top-grade security against DNS hijacking (or for hosting, unauthorized access).